# how to render an html file with Microsoft Word html renderer in a fast way?

Tags: html, browser, dll, ms-word, html-rendering

Is there a way to render an html file with the Microsoft Word 2007+?

I mean, maybe some browser that could use the html renderer of Microsoft Word?, or maybe take the dll files and make some program and then render the html file?

I can take the html file and drag it into the Microsoft Word but I want something faster like once the html file is loaded, if I make some changes on the html file I just need to press F5 and see how Microsoft Word renders the new version.

What I need is to test the changes on Microsoft Word somehow, because this renderer is very peculiar.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why opening `.html` files using MS Word? Why not generate `.doc` (or some other) file? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: Perhaps (I haven't tried) create an empty Word document and use an INCLUDETEXT field to insert the .html file. Then use ctrl-A, F9 to update the field result each time you change the .html